# PHP IF-Statement doesnt work like i want

Tags: php, if-statement, logic, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I recently started writing a website for learning html/css/js/php.

I designed the front-end of my site with bootstrap.
Now I am trying to validate some inputs with PHP.

I tried this:

```
    if ($durationHH <= 0 && $durationMM <= 0)
    {
        echo "DurationHH and DurationMM can not be both zero at the same time.";    
        echo "<br>";
        echo "DurationHH and DurationMM can not be smaller than 0.";       
    }
    elseif (empty($durationHH) || empty($durationMM))
    {       
        echo "DurationHH and DurationMM can not be empty.";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $_POST["durationMM"];
        echo ":";
        echo $_POST["durationHH"];
    }
```

I tested the validation by putting in some values for durationHH and durationMM.

Everything is working fine so far, except these two cases:

durationMM = 0 AND durationHH = any value

&&

durationHH= 0 AND durationMM = any value.

In these two cases i get the output: "DurationHH and DurationMM can not be empty."

How/why does this happen?

Comment: `0` is empty in that case, so change to `$durationHH == '' || $durationMM == ''` or you can use like `is_numeric`

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2220519/5447994) may give you idea

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working now ^^

Answer (score 0):

if durationHH and durationMM are always required to be integers or numeric, use `! is_numeric()` to check.