# Could this expression ever be false?

Tags: php, casting, logical-operators, boolean-logic, isset

I am checking some code and I am wondering if this expression could ever be `false`:

```
!isset($_POST['foo']) || $_POST['foo']
```

Context:

```
$bar = (!isset($_POST['foo']) || $_POST['foo']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: If the value of `$_POST['foo']` is an empty string it would be `false`

Comment: `isset()` does not check if something is empty. Those are mostly used for radios, checkboxes, select inputs. What is it exactly that you want to check against?

Comment: It basically states that if `$_POST['foo']` **is not** set or if it has a value, we're all good - so, yeah it looks like it's explicitly looking for empty form fields; this may fall over with `<textarea>` fields mind - they're not posted if empty - so an empty `<input type="text" ... />` would set `$bar` to `0` whereas for a `<textarea>` it would be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

According to a quick test below, it is indeed possible

```
$trueVar = true; // Or 1
$falseVar = false; // Or 0
$nullVar = null;
$emptyVar = "";

$result1 = (!isset($trueVar) || $trueVar) ? 1 : 0;
$result2 = (!isset($falseVar) || $falseVar) ? 1 : 0;
$result3 = (!isset($nullVar) || $nullVar) ? 1 : 0;
$result4 = (!isset($emptyVar) || $emptyVar) ? 1 : 0;

Output: 
result1 = 1
result2 = 0
result3 = 1
result4 = 0
```

Note: Why don't you just simply do `$bar = isset($_POST['foo'])` and adquire if it's empty or not?

Edit: Funk Forty Niner is correctt isset($_POST) will always return true because it's always set due to being a global variable, `empty()` should be used instead or another approach

https://3v4l.org/EtWn0

Comment: I was actually wrong about isset on **null** value, so this thread is also worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could think of the following cases:

- **$_POST['foo'] doesn't exist**

$bar = (true || null) ? 1 : 0 => 1

- **$_POST['foo'] exists and value is anything but 0, false or empty string**

$bar = (false || true) ? 1 : 0 => 1

- **$_POST['foo'] exists and value is 0, false, empty string**

$bar = (false || false) ? 1 : 0 => 0

- **$_POST['foo'] exists and value is null**

$bar = (true || false) ? 1 : 0 => 1

I think you should read this [In php, is 0 treated as empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220519/in-php-is-0-treated-as-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement:

```
!isset($_POST['foo']) || $_POST['foo']
```

Pseudo-Code with wods:

```
NOT isset($_POST['foo']) OR $_POST['foo']
```

Not has a higher binding than the OR operator (http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.logical.php).

What you are really asking: *Does `isset($_POST['foo'])` always evaluate to the same result as `$_POST['foo']`?*

**Definition of the isset function:**

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

*Therefore isset only evaluates to false if a variable is not existing and not null.*

**Automatically casting to Boolean:**

A plain variable in PHP in a boolean condition evaluates to `false` under the following conditions:

> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements the
> - special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php . As you can see there are a lot of cases where this is not the same.

What your code means in words: **If the variable is one of 0,0.0,"","0",[] or an empty XML object return 1.**